# Drawing the Axis with its arrow using OpenGL in visual studio 2010 and c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

using openGL, I can draw the Axis (x,y and z) in the center of screen, But I can not draw their arrows at the end of each line. in 2d I saw an example code which using GL_LINE_STRIP, but in 3D, I googled alot and I did not find any example; 
Now I just put a point at the end of each line; but Actually it is very ugly.

How can I draw it? 
this code is just draw the cylinder of z axe in proper position; How can I set others?

```
void Axis_3D (void)
{
    GLUquadric* cyl = gluNewQuadric();
    GLUquadric* cy2 = gluNewQuadric();
    GLUquadric* cy3 = gluNewQuadric();

   // gluCylinder (cyl, 0.02, 0.02, 4, 16, 1);        // Body of axis.

    glColor3f (1,1,1);                                // Make arrow head white.
    glPushMatrix ();
       glTranslatef (0.0,0.0,4);
       gluCylinder(cyl, 0.04, 0.000, 0.1, 12,1);   // Cone at end of axis.

       glTranslatef (0.0,4,0.0);
       gluCylinder  (cy2, 0.04, 0.001, 0.1, 12,1);

       glTranslatef (4,0.0,0.0);
       gluCylinder  (cy3, 0.04, 0.001, 0.1, 12,1);
    glPopMatrix ();
}
```

thank you so much!

Comment: Have you considered capping the axes with cones (they're basically a 3D extrapolation of the arrowheads you would see on a 2D graph)? This can be done as simply as creating a cylinder with a radius of 0.0 at one end using something like `gluCylinder (...)`. Granted, GLU quadrics are deprecated, but it will get the job done really quickly if you're not required to use OpenGL 3.2 core or newer.

Comment: which values should I pass as its parameters?

Comment: Since it is part of a larger system known as GLU quadrics, I would suggest you look at a tutorial to see how this would be done. You can find one that does exactly this [here](http://jerome.jouvie.free.fr/opengl-tutorials/Tutorial7.php). The tutorial's written for Java, but the API is basically the same.

Comment: I can not understand what is wrong; in screen I can not see any cylinder! can you send an example code please?

Comment: can you explain the logic of geometry that you use in this code? I move the arrows to the last of lines, but now I need to know each  parameters to change the size of them :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use those functions to draw arrows in a cutey little simulation program. Have fun using them :)

```
#define RADPERDEG 0.0174533

void Arrow(GLdouble x1,GLdouble y1,GLdouble z1,GLdouble x2,GLdouble y2,GLdouble z2,GLdouble D)
{
  double x=x2-x1;
  double y=y2-y1;
  double z=z2-z1;
  double L=sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);

    GLUquadricObj *quadObj;

    glPushMatrix ();

      glTranslated(x1,y1,z1);

      if((x!=0.)||(y!=0.)) {
        glRotated(atan2(y,x)/RADPERDEG,0.,0.,1.);
        glRotated(atan2(sqrt(x*x+y*y),z)/RADPERDEG,0.,1.,0.);
      } else if (z<0){
        glRotated(180,1.,0.,0.);
      }

      glTranslatef(0,0,L-4*D);

      quadObj = gluNewQuadric ();
      gluQuadricDrawStyle (quadObj, GLU_FILL);
      gluQuadricNormals (quadObj, GLU_SMOOTH);
      gluCylinder(quadObj, 2*D, 0.0, 4*D, 32, 1);
      gluDeleteQuadric(quadObj);

      quadObj = gluNewQuadric ();
      gluQuadricDrawStyle (quadObj, GLU_FILL);
      gluQuadricNormals (quadObj, GLU_SMOOTH);
      gluDisk(quadObj, 0.0, 2*D, 32, 1);
      gluDeleteQuadric(quadObj);

      glTranslatef(0,0,-L+4*D);

      quadObj = gluNewQuadric ();
      gluQuadricDrawStyle (quadObj, GLU_FILL);
      gluQuadricNormals (quadObj, GLU_SMOOTH);
      gluCylinder(quadObj, D, D, L-4*D, 32, 1);
      gluDeleteQuadric(quadObj);

      quadObj = gluNewQuadric ();
      gluQuadricDrawStyle (quadObj, GLU_FILL);
      gluQuadricNormals (quadObj, GLU_SMOOTH);
      gluDisk(quadObj, 0.0, D, 32, 1);
      gluDeleteQuadric(quadObj);

    glPopMatrix ();

}
void drawAxes(GLdouble length)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-length,0,0);
    Arrow(0,0,0, 2*length,0,0, 0.2);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0,-length,0);
    Arrow(0,0,0, 0,2*length,0, 0.2);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0,0,-length);
    Arrow(0,0,0, 0,0,2*length, 0.2);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: what is RADPERDEG here?

Comment: @GolnazSaraji It's radians per degree. I added it to the code.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman well linguistically you may be right, but in the program that's the value :)

Comment: sorry but this code draw a very big arrows on the origin of axes; it is not that I want :( How can I send you the output picture ?

Comment: @GolnazSaraji if the arrows are big, make them smaller! If you don't want them at the origin, move them with glTranslatef() or glTranslated(). You can edit them as you want ;)

Comment: :D but I thought when I say I want arrows in Axis it is clear where is their Position and there is no need to set them:)) By the way thank you so much!

Comment: @GolnazSaraji In OpenGL, you always draw objects at origin and shift/rotate them with glTranslatef()/glRotatef(). That's the way it works! Symmetries around the origin is an important feature that you have to make use of when drawing with equations, like you do in OpenGL.

Comment: thank you thank you soooo much The Quantum :) that is very effective advices to me :)

Comment: @GolnazSaraji You're welcome. Since you're a beginner in OpenGL, don't forget to learn the concept of glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix(), which help you in rotating and translating individual objects, because when you use glTranslatef(), for example, everything will move, so you have to push, translate, then pop, as it's shown in the code. If the answer satisfied you, accept it. Good luck!

Comment: ok! but can you tell me what is the rule of moving the shapes to the end of lines?

Comment: @GolnazSaraji I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean which part of code I must change to draw the arrow at the end of lines?

Comment: @GolnazSaraji You have the function drawAxes() which is split into 3 parts from drawing each axis. Each part shifts the stage to '-length' and then plots a line with length '2*length'. So if you want all axes to start from the same point, just don't make them shift! And control their length starting from there.

Comment: No I just want to shift the arrows at the end of each lines!

Comment: @GolnazSaraji I explained how you can do that. Just play with the code a little, and you'll know how to do it. You have to gain a little bit more experience.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of geometry in your code? I change the start position of each arrows and now I need to know each parameter to change the size of them :)

Comment: @GolnazSaraji You don't need to know the details on the Arrow() function. There you just give the starting and ending position of your arrow and its thickness to draw it. And about the axes function; for each axis, you move your stage to the starting position of the axis, and then you draw the axis. Try to play with the code to learn what it changes.

Answer (score 2):

When I hacked my frustum illustration program I wrote a little arrow drawing helper function `draw_arrow`, that draws an screen aligned arrow + annotation (uses glutStorkeCharacter).

Note that it uses the fixed function pipeline modelview matrix to determine the local space base vectors. If you want to use it in a shader based pipeline you'll have to pass the modelview matrix into it by an additional parameter.

https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/frustum/frustum.c

```
void draw_arrow(
    float ax, float ay, float az,  /* starting point in local space */
    float bx, float by, float bz,  /* starting point in local space */
    float ah, float bh,            /* arrow head size start and end */
    char const * const annotation, /* annotation string */
    float annot_size               /* annotation string height (local units) */ )
{
    int i;

    GLdouble mv[16];
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mv);

    /* We're assuming the modelview RS part is (isotropically scaled)
     * orthonormal, so the inverse is the transpose.
     * The local view direction vector is the 3rd column of the matrix;
     * assuming the view direction to be the normal on the arrows tangent
     * space  taking the cross product of this with the arrow direction
     * yields the binormal to be used as the orthonormal base to the 
     * arrow direction to be used for drawing the arrowheads */

    double d[3] = {
          bx - ax,
          by - ay,
          bz - az
    };
    normalize_v(d);

    double r[3] = { mv[0], mv[4], mv[8] };
    int rev = scalarproduct_v(d, r) < 0.;

    double n[3] = { mv[2], mv[6], mv[10] };
    {
        double const s = scalarproduct_v(d,n);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            n[i] -= d[i]*s;
    }
    normalize_v(n);

    double b[3];
    crossproduct_v(n, d, b);

    /* Make a 60° arrowhead ( sin(60°) = 0.866... ) */
    GLfloat const pos[][3] = {
        {ax, ay, az},
        {bx, by, bz},
        { ax + (0.866*d[0] + 0.5*b[0])*ah,
          ay + (0.866*d[1] + 0.5*b[1])*ah,
          az + (0.866*d[2] + 0.5*b[2])*ah },
        { ax + (0.866*d[0] - 0.5*b[0])*ah,
          ay + (0.866*d[1] - 0.5*b[1])*ah,
          az + (0.866*d[2] - 0.5*b[2])*ah },
        { bx + (-0.866*d[0] + 0.5*b[0])*bh,
          by + (-0.866*d[1] + 0.5*b[1])*bh,
          bz + (-0.866*d[2] + 0.5*b[2])*bh },
        { bx + (-0.866*d[0] - 0.5*b[0])*bh,
          by + (-0.866*d[1] - 0.5*b[1])*bh,
          bz + (-0.866*d[2] - 0.5*b[2])*bh }
    };
    GLushort const idx[][2] = {
        {0, 1},
        {0, 2}, {0, 3},
        {1, 4}, {1, 5}
    };
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, pos);

    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 2*5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, idx);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    if(annotation) {
        float w = 0;
        for(char const *c = annotation; *c; c++)
            w += glutStrokeWidth(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, *c);
        w *= annot_size / 100.;

        float tx = (ax + bx)/2.;
        float ty = (ay + by)/2.;
        float tz = (az + bz)/2.;

        GLdouble r[16] = {
            d[0], d[1], d[2], 0,
            b[0], b[1], b[2], 0,
            n[0], n[1], n[2], 0,
               0,    0,    0, 1
        };
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(tx, ty, tz);
        glMultMatrixd(r);
        if(rev)
            glScalef(-1, -1, 1);
        glTranslatef(-w/2., annot_size*0.1, 0);
        draw_strokestring(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, annot_size, annotation);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Help yourself.

Comment: @GolnazSaraji: I do understand that this code may look like "magic" to someone not fluent in linear algebra. But what it does is actually rather simple: For a given line there's a plane to the which the line is perpendicular. It determines which vector in that plane is aiming at the viewer. Then the vector perpendicular to the line, and the direction to the viewer is determined, which forms the y-base for the local coordinate system in which the arrowhead is drawn. The normalized line direction forms the local xz-base for the arrowhead. That is then used to calculate the vertex positions.

Comment: you mean I must call this for each axe in my Draw_Axes function?

Comment: @GolnazSaraji: Yes, that would do the trick. You can set the color using `glColor` as usual. But take notice, that this is written for the fixed function pipeline.

Comment: @GolnazSaraji: The code snippet I put into the answer just coveres the arrow drawing code; it however lacks the vector manipulation functions defines right before it. You can find them in the codesample I linked right before the code snippet. There's no requirement for any other headers than the standard OpenGL header; I was however intending to make it use my linmath.h library, but so far it's independent from it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the help of The Quantum Physicist and merge it with my own code, at last draw this Axes :

```
#define RADPERDEG 0.0174533
void Arrow(GLdouble x1,GLdouble y1,GLdouble z1,GLdouble x2,GLdouble y2,GLdouble z2,GLdouble D)
{
  double x=x2-x1;
  double y=y2-y1;
  double z=z2-z1;
  double L=sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);

    GLUquadricObj *quadObj;
    GLUquadric* cyl = gluNewQuadric();
    GLUquadric* cy2 = gluNewQuadric();
    GLUquadric* cy3 = gluNewQuadric();
    glPushMatrix ();

      glTranslated(x1,y1,z1);

      if((x!=0.)||(y!=0.)) {
        glRotated(atan2(y,x)/RADPERDEG,0.,0.,1.);
        glRotated(atan2(sqrt(x*x+y*y),z)/RADPERDEG,0.,1.,0.);
      } else if (z<0){
        glRotated(180,1.,0.,0.);
      }

      glTranslatef(0,0,L-4*D);

      gluQuadricDrawStyle (cyl, GLU_FILL);
      gluQuadricNormals (cyl, GLU_SMOOTH);
      glColor3f (1,1,1); 
      glTranslatef (0.0,0.0,4);
      gluCylinder(cyl, 0.04, 0.0, 1.0, 12,1);
      gluDeleteQuadric(cyl);

      glTranslatef(0,0,-L+4*D);

      gluQuadricDrawStyle (cy2, GLU_FILL);
      gluQuadricNormals (cy2, GLU_SMOOTH);
      glColor3f (1,1,1);
      glTranslatef (0.0,4,0.0);
      gluCylinder(cy2, 0.4, 0.4,L-1.6, 12,1);
      gluDeleteQuadric(cy2);

    glPopMatrix();

}
void drawAxes(GLdouble length)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-length,0,0);
    Arrow(0,0,0, 2*length,0,0,0.2);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0,-length,0);
    Arrow(0,0,0, 0,2*length,0,0.2);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0,0,-length);
    Arrow(0,0,0, 0,0,2*length,0.2);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```